# ORA - 00936 error but anable to find what is missing in line 2

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, row-number, ora-00936

I'm trying to execute this code but it says i'm missing something in `row_number()` expression which I'm not able to figure out at all.

```
with summary as 
(select s.city, length(s.city) as C_length, 
row_number() over (partition by length(s.city), order by s.city)
as r1 from station s
where 
length(s.city) = (SELECT min(LENGTH(s1.CITY)) FROM STATION s1)
or length(s.city) = (SELECT max(LENGTH(s2.CITY)) FROM STATION s2))
select su.city, su.C_length 
from summary su;
```

Comment: You are not using `r1` so there is no need to calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be simplified:

```
with summary as (
      select s.city, length(s.city) as C_length, 
             min(length(s.city)) over () as min_length,
             max(length(s.city)) over () as max_length,
      from station s
     )
select su.city, su.C_length 
from summary su
where c_length in (min_length, max_length);
```

I removed `r1` because it is not being used.

Comment: Thank you. so min(length(s.city)) over () as min_length would work ?
can you explain what funtion is called suring "over ()" please ?

Comment: @Vish . . . I don't understand your comment.  The code seems pretty clear:  it is calculating the minimum length of the city over all the data.

Comment: I meant that the paranthesis was not enclosing anything inside it right ?

Comment: @Vish . . . That is the syntax for a window/analytic function.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a comma between the `partition by` clause and the `order by` clause. Just remove it and you should be OK:

```
row_number() over (partition by length(s.city) order by s.city)
-- Comma removed here ------------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you very much. will do so